# Optimizing graphql database queries

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Lets say we have following graphql schema:

```
type Author : Object {  
  id: ID!
  name: String,
  books: [Book]
}

type Book : Object {  
  id: ID!
  title: String
  authorId: Int
  author: Author
}
```

And then making a query like:

```
{
    books: {
        id 
        title
        author { id name }
    }
}
```

If, for example, we have 10 books, then we will end up with 10 author queries, as the resolve function will be called for each fetched book:

```
select id, name from author where id = 123
```

Instead of this we can execute all author queries as a single query:

```
select id, name from author where id in (123, 456, 789, 1011)
```

Is there some working solutions, best practices, techniques or something that can help to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dataloader is your answer, it has batching feature which means that it will queue all the ids. And only once its ready it will pull it as a batch
Demo can be found here:
https://youtu.be/UBGzsb2UkeY (Last 5 minutes in particular)
Algorithem explained can be found here:
https://youtu.be/OQTnXNCDywA

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 5):

[DataLoader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) is a great database-agnostic solution. If you're using SQL, [Join Monster](https://github.com/stems/join-monster) is more tailored for relational DBs and will even translate the GraphQL queries to SQL directly with a single round-trip. Another alternative is [graph-joiner](https://github.com/mwilliamson/node-graphjoiner).